# Bug with rotateY and z-index in Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, transform

I have block with 2 sides. I use rotateY for show back side.

Its perfect work at google Chrome, but didn't work in Safari.

Example in Chrome http://joxi.ru/DmB71KyFEDjR2P

Example in Safari http://joxi.ru/Y2L8p1MsKlbO26

I thought that the case z-index, but it does not help

Look it on [dev.buuza.org/?id_category=87](http://dev.buuza.org/?id_category=87)

Comment: I met the same problem

Comment: @JackPu iam solves it. mb not ideal. but mb it help u http buuza.org